# remove p element from DOM tree with javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, css-selectors, getelementsbyclassname

This should be a simple one, and yet I need help to solve the problem:
I need to remove the element with the class "goup" on it from the DOM tree
with javascript (eventually with prototype, but no other library).
I don't only want to hide that paragraph, but remove it entirely from the DOM tree.

My solution to use getElementsByClassName does not work.

```
function hidegoup() {
    var goup= document.getElementsByTagName("p")
        .getElementsByClassName("goup"); 
     goup.style.display = 'none';   
     goup.removeChild();
}
```

THE HTML:

```
<div id="poems">
    <div class="poem" id="d1">
        <p class="goup">
        <a href="#">To the top of the page</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if you want to remove a `node` from the DOM, use:

```
node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
```

as to what you want to do:

```
function hidegoup() {
    var p_list = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    for(var i=p_list.length-1; i>=0; i--){
        var p = p_list[i];
        if(p.className === "goup"){
            p.parentNode.removeChild(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `getElementsByClassName` returns a NodeList, not a Node. You have to iterate over it with a `for` loop
2. `getElementsByClassName` is not supported except in recent browsers, you should probably use [a library that abstracts the differences away](http://microjs.com/#css)
3. `removeChild` removes the specified child of the element upon which it is called: `parent.removeChild(child);`, you don't call it on the element you want to remove directly.

Comment: Is getElementsByClassName () an official Method in DOM Spec level 2 and 3?

Comment: I don't think so. It does appear in the HTML 5 draft though.